# Openlayers - Enable interaction after map initialization

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using openlayers 6.5.

Here is how I start:

```
/*** Set the map ***/
map = new ol.Map({
    target: map_element,
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([
            '24.6859225',
            '45.9852129',
        ]),
        zoom: 6,
    }),
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        'DragPan': false,
        'Keyboard': false,
        'PinchZoom': false,
        'ZoomDelta': false,
        'PinchRotate': false,
        'OnFocusOnly': false,
        'ZoomDuration': false,
        'ShiftDragZoom': false,
        'MouseWheelZoom': false,
        'DoubleClickZoom': false,
        'AltShiftDragRotate': false
    }),
    controls: [],
});
```

I want to be able, **after map initialization**, to enable and disable each interaction.

I found the next code posted on stack (enable DragPan):

```
map.getInteractions().forEach((interaction) => {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragPan) {
        interaction.setActive(true);
    }
});
```

But the next one doesn't work:

```
map.getInteractions().forEach((interaction) => {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.AltShiftDragRotate) {
        interaction.setActive(true);
    }
});
```

The error: `Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`

Some help ?

Comment: The interactions in the defaults https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction.html#~defaults do not have the same names as the options

Comment: @Mike, Yes, that's true, but that doesn't seem to be a problem. Replacing `AltShiftDragRotate` with `altShiftDragRotate` has no effect. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ol.interaction.defaults` with `false` options (the option names should be in `camelCase` format) you should use

```
var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults();
interactions.forEach((interaction) => {
    interaction.setActive(false);
});
```

as setting the options false excludes some interactions instead of setting them disabled

`altShiftDragRotate` is option name used to disable (or perhaps exclude) the DragRotate interaction, so the interaction class needed is `ol.interaction.DragRotate`

```
interactions.forEach((interaction) => {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragRotate) {
        interaction.setActive(true);
    }
});
```